# Is there a word for a picture of a face that is made from the letters of a name?

Tags: single-word-requests

Does anybody know if there is a name for a picture of a face made from the actual letters of a name?

This picture from the band T'Pau's album cover is a good example what I'm looking for - [Heart and Soul album cover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heart_and_Soul_%28T%27Pau_song%29)

I saw a set of them at an art gallery years ago that used different people's first names, but I haven't been able to find anything since and no look with google.

Comment: Nitpicky, but which album cover? I can't see the image you've posted.

Comment: Pictures made of characters are commonly called *ASCII art*, but I wouldn't call that album cover ASCII.

Comment: It was the cover of "Heart and Soul". Try this link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heart_and_Soul_(T'Pau_song)

Comment: @Leo - I'm guessing it's [this one](http://burningtheground.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/A.-Front4.jpg)

Comment: Gotcha. I agree that's not ASCII art.

Comment: [Henohenomoheji](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henohenomoheji) (へのへのもへじ) or hehenonomoheji (へへののもへじ) is related. It is a face drawn using hiragana characters.

Comment: It's a *calligram.*

Answer (score 2):

This image appears to be an **[autologlyph](http://www.segerman.org/autologlyphs.html)** as illustrated at segerman.org.

This form of expression is discussed in out sister site, Graphic Design, [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/22416/whats-the-name-for-typography-that-looks-like-the-meaning-of-its-content).

The technique has also been called *[visual onomatopoeia](http://blogs.scientificamerican.com/symbiartic/2013/06/25/word-as-image-ji-lee-onomatopoeia-for-your-eyes/)* as illustrated in *Scientific American*

Lauren Ipsum has suggested a neologism, *[fontomatopoeia](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/22416/whats-the-name-for-typography-that-looks-like-the-meaning-of-its-content)*.